# Custom Header Will Not Load 'Failed to load resource: the sever responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-image, custom-headers

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com

When the device width is greater than 601px I want the following to happen

1. I don't want there to ever be any space between the menu and the
   custom header
2. I don't want there to ever be any space above the customer header
3. I don't want H1, the plugins or any other content on the page to ever overlap the customer header
4. I don't want there to ever be any white space to the left or right of the customer header
5. I want to always be able to see the whole text 'Ross The Explorer', I don't want the last R to ever be removed

Look at www.nomadicmatt.com for an idea on what I want to achieve.

To put the custom-header in its own row I tried to use the following code

```
   <div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
  <div class="custom-header"></div>
</div>

 </div>
```

This appeared to have no effect.

Here is the complete header.php code.

```
 <?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<

    head>
    <meta charset="<?ph

p bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?php wp_title( 'A|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-

        Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script

>


</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>


  <div class="custom-header"></div>



<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'jetpack_the_site_logo' ) ) jetpack_the_site_logo(); ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'penscratch' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

            </a>
        <?php endif;  // End header image check. ?>
```

In Additional CSS I have the following code

```
@media screen and (min-width: 75em)
{
  .site {
    max-width: 1153px;
    margin: 400px auto;
    padding: 54px 108px;
  }
}



@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
 .custom-header { background: url("https://i1.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg") no-repeat; 
        width: 100% ;
                        background-size:contain;


    }
}
```

After including the new code, loading http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/themes/penscratch/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css and http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/themes/penscratch/js/bootstrap.min.js still results in a 404 error (not found).

Can people give me suggestions on other code I could try?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is your code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px)?custom-css=d4d401c306:9

.custom-header {
    background: url(https://i1.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg) no-repeat;

    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

/* change background-size: cover; to background-size: 100%;   */

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 601px)?custom-css=d4d401c306:9

.custom-header {
    background: url(https://i1.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg) no-repeat;

    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

The R in 'Explorer' is no longer being cut although there is still issues with spacing between the customer header and other elements of the page.

Comment: You will need to trial and error your padding and margin on your custom  header and your navbar. It is very populated so you will have difficulty achieving this. Perhaps try adding padding to your site content to drop down your main container - that will give you some room to work with.

Comment: My custom header is now not loading. I get the error message 

Failed to load resource: the sever responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It looks liek you have broken some code, are you using a plugin for  your custom header. If so try deleting it and re-installing it.